# IE8 - Geocode Ajax call never succeeds

Tags: ajax, json, internet-explorer-8, geocoding

Please excuse my bad english, I'm french ;)

SO, I've to make an Ajax call you this kind of url :
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=45.85941212790755,0&sensor=true

With this code :

```
$.ajax({ url:'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+pos.coords.latitude+','+pos.coords.longitude+'&sensor=true',
          success: function(results){
              // ...
          }
        });
```

But it never succeeds for IE8 (It's ok for chrome and FF, IE9&10).

Have you got an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

My bad, in IE8 you cannot request a geocode from the client side any longer because google has removed `JSONP` support from their geocoder.

You can do one of two things

1. Use your own server as a proxy (I do this). 
   This basically means that you make a request to a script on your own server that uses cURL (or similar) to make a request to the google geocoder and then return the results back to you.
2. If you're using the google maps api, you have the option of using it's built-in geocoder (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple)

**OLD REPLY**

It's a cross domain call in IE8 - you'll get a `No Transport` error (or if you add `jQuery.support.cors = true` you'll still get an `Access is Denied` error.

Best solutions is to use `JSONP`. jQuery makes using `JSONP` trivial.

Check out this [jQuery Docs page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) and scroll down to their example using JSONP with the Flickr API.

Comment: I've got a No Transport Exception from IE8 with JSONP... (for geocode)